# Using the MAX function to get the latest values based on the "Creation Date/Time"

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to get the **latest** data from an **observation table**.  To make sure I get the latest value, I'm using the max function on the value's "creation date/time".  And to narrow my results down to a specific patient, I have to join this table to the **Patient Table**.
I would love to send out a visual of the table but can't since it's my first post.  Anyways, see if you can figure it out without the table design.

I executed the following:

```
select  o.FindingName, o.Value, o.CreationTime          
from    dbo.HObservation o inner join dbo.HPatient p
    on p.ObjectID = o.Patient_oid,               
    (select max(CreationTime) as CT, value
        from    dbo.HObservation group by Value ) b
        Where o.Value = b.Value and 
        o.CreationTime = b.CT
                   and o.FindingAbbr in ( 'Wt', 'A_BM', 'A_Last BM Date', 'A_BP',  
        'A_Pulse', 'A_Temperature', 'A_Respirations', 
        'A_R_SurgDate', 'A_R_ChRvORTm', 'A_R_OpPOPPreced'
        , 'A_R_FNSNN', 'A_R_WOUNDNN') 
                and p.ObjectID = 2227268
```

My results appear to display all the data listed on the table above.
I tried multiple scenarios but my brain is a bit fried right now, I can't even remember them.  Does anyone know what i'm doing wrong here?
Also, as you may have noticed I tried to narrow my list of "finding Names" to 12 values only.  Just to make it a bit more efficient but that didn't help none.
Any ideas!!??

Answer (score 0):

Is HObservation table will have records / value field for each Patients.

On your query

```
(select max(CreationTime) as CT, value         from    dbo.HObservation group by Value )
```

you are taking the max of time by value only. if your table has multiple patients then it will list only the max of value for those patients which is recently updated.

You can include Patient_oid column along with the value to get max (creationTime)

Answer (score 0):

You left some details out of your question:

1. Which version of MS SQL Server you are using. I assume SQL2005 or more recent so that CTE's and the ranking function ROW_NUMBER() can be used.
2. Whether you want the most recent value of each observation for a given patient, or all values for the patient observed at the most recent time any observation was made for the patient. I assume the former.

This query should give you the general idea:

```
with WindowedObservation as (
    select Patient_oid, FindingAbbr, Value, CreationTime,
        row_number() over (
            partition by Patient_oid, FindingAbbr
            order by CreationTime desc
        ) as ROWNUM
    from HObservation
)
select *
from WindowedObservation
join HPatient
on HPatient.ObjectId = WindowedObservation.Patient_oid
where WindowedObservation.ROWNUM = 1
```

Comment out the WHERE clause to see how ROW_NUMBER() is being used.

Here is a small amount of sample data to test with:

```
CREATE TABLE HPatient (
    ObjectId int,
    Name nvarchar(50)
)

insert into HPatient(ObjectId, Name)
select 1,'Patient1'
union all select 2, 'Patient2'
union all select 3,'Patient3'

CREATE TABLE HObservation (
    Patient_oid int,
    FindingAbbr nvarchar(50),
    Value float,
    CreationTime datetime
)

insert into HObservation(Patient_oid, FindingAbbr, Value, CreationTime)
select 1, 'A_Pulse', 64, '2012-01-01'
union all select 1, 'A_Pulse', 73, '2012-01-02'
union all select 1, 'A_Pulse', 59, '2012-01-03'
union all select 1, 'A_Temperature', 98.6, '2012-01-01'
union all select 1, 'A_Temperature', 98.1, '2012-01-02'
union all select 1, 'A_Temperature', 90.2, '2012-01-03'
union all select 2, 'A_Pulse', 61, '2012-01-03'
union all select 2, 'A_Pulse', 67, '2012-01-04'
union all select 2, 'A_Pulse', 64, '2012-01-05'
union all select 2, 'A_Temperature', 100.2, '2012-01-03'
union all select 2, 'A_Temperature', 98.6, '2012-01-04'
union all select 2, 'A_Temperature', 98.9, '2012-01-05'
union all select 3, 'A_Pulse', 80, '2012-02-01'
union all select 3, 'A_Temperature', 98.2, '2012-02-01'
union all select 3, 'Wt', 180, '2012-02-01'
union all select 3, 'A_Pulse', 84, '2012-02-02'
union all select 3, 'A_Respirations', 16, '2012-02-03'
```